# Function stops with no errors after add eventGrid as out binding

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure function with a `blobTrigger` as input and an `Azure Storage Table` as output.
It is working without any problem.

Now, I try to **add** an event grid topic as a binding output in a function.

This is the new `fuction.json` (added a new eventGrid out):

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "landedFile",
      "path": "landing/{name}",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "xxTable",
      "tableName": "xxTable",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"
    },
    {
      "type": "eventGrid",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "xxEvent",
      "topicEndpointUri": "AZURE_TOPIC_XX_ENDPOINT",
      "topicKeySetting": "AZURE_TOPIC_XX_KEY"
    }
  ]
}
```

The value of `AZURE_TOPIC_XX_ENDPOINT` is:

```
az eventgrid topic show \
  --name $topicName \
  --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
  --query endpoint \
  --output tsv
```

The value of `AZURE_TOPIC_XX_KEY` is:

```
az eventgrid topic key list \
  --name $topicName \
  --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
  --query key1 \
  --output tsv
```

I double-checked that `key1` is one of the keys.

I publish the app with no errors, but:

- When I check the function in the portal:

  - **Code + Test** shows the code with no problems.
  - **Integration** is blank instead to show the diagram. I mean, it does not show anything. Completely blank.
  - **Monitor -> Invocations** does not show any errors or success call.
- When I update a file to the storage, it is not triggering the function.

Please, help. I don't know what could be wrong or where to find any clue or error message.

Comment: For double check:  Can you see the topic endpoint address url and its access key in the Application settings?

Comment: Also, could you add your code for output on the topic?

Comment: @RomanKiss I don't forget it, but this is part of a side project so I need to find time to work on it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

I found someone facing the same problem here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48921

The root of the problem here is the `ExtensionBundle` provided by Microsoft did not have `eventGrid` *output* binding, only the `eventGrid` *trigger* binding. This causing the `eventGrid` output binding not to be included in the bundle. Therefore, your error. I can see this has been added in the latest release 1.2.0+, but it seems that it hasn't been released yet.

What I would recommend you to do in the meantime is to work around the issue by simply posting to EventGrid. Here's an example using Node.js.

```js
await axios.post(process.env["EventGridEndpoint"], ceEvent.format(), {
    headers: {
        'aeg-sas-key': process.env["EventGridKey"],
        'Content-Type': 'application/cloudevents+json'
    }
});
```

The `EventGridEndpoint` attribute you can get it on the summary page of the EventGrid Topic you create, and `EventGridKey` is under the key section.

You can see the full Microsoft documentation of how to work with EventGrid directly here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/edge/api

Finally, the reason it's not triggering the Function after you add the EventGrid out binding is that the error is now a host-level error before your Function can be loaded and executed. You can debug this by going to Application Insights and run the following query:

```
traces
| where message contains "eventGrid"
```

and you will see something like this:

```
The 'xxxxx' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'eventGrid' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
```

Comment: Instead of just linking to the issue, can you provide a summary of what the issue is here on Stack Overflow so that readers don't need to click through to the link? Likewise, if you have code that solves the problem, it may be useful to other readers to provide that here so the community can benefit from it.